# Flex 3 - Using error tooltips as normal ones

Tags: apache-flex, validation, tooltip

I'd like to use tooltips with the same design as the error/validation tooltips (rounded box with a tip pointing to the mouse's position).

Given the name "error/validation tooltips", it bothers me to use them as normal tooltips.I haven't found people having the same "principles" issue as myself..

So, is it that bad to use the error/validation tooltips as normal tooltips? And, if yes, what would be the easiest way to re-use its design without rewriting much code?

Hope it's clear enough :) And that you will be able to enlighten me somehow in this matter :)

Regards. 
BS_C3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good or Bad is subjective based on what you're trying to do and the design of your app.    There is never a right a wrong answer to stuff like that.

To reuse that design, you have two options that I see.

1. The first is to set the styleName of your toolTip component to errorTip.
2. The second is open up the default.css in the Flex Framework directory and copy and paste the CSS for the errorTip into your own CSS file that you then use in your application.

[These docs will be good reading on this issue](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=tooltips_5.html).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I finally found something similar to your second solution :) But now I'm encountering another issue... I'll create a new question for that. Thanks again